# How to find a node in a binary tree using an attribute of the object

Tags: java

I have a generic binary tree. What I want to do is find a node, providing an attribute to find that node an then return it.
For example, my tree has Objects type X, X has an attribute code, so I have to compare the code of the current node with the code provided.

```
private X find_X_by_code(Node<X> node, String code) {
    if (!node.element.code().equals(code)){
        if (node.left != null){
            find_X_by_code(node.left,code);
        }
        if (node.right != null){
            find_X_by_code(node.right,code);
        }
    }
    return node.element;
}
```

I call this method like this:

```
find_X_by_code(root,code);
```

For some reason when the codes match, it keeps going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to tweak a little depending upon your use.

```
if(node != null){
    if(node.element.code().equals(code)){
       return node.element;
    } else {
        Node tempNode = find_X_by_code(node.left, code);
        if(tempNode == null) {
            tempNode = find_X_by_code(node.right, code);
        }
        return tempNode.element;
     }
} else {
    return null;
}
```

[How to search for a node in a tree and return it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938486/how-to-search-for-a-node-in-a-tree-and-return-it)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the returns in the recursive calls and a handle for the case when the node isn't present (reach null). Change it to:

```
private X find_X_by_code(Node<X> node, String code) {
    if (node == null) { return null; }
    if (!node.element.code().equals(code)){
        if (node.left != null){
            return find_X_by_code(node.left,code);
        }
        if (node.right != null){
            return find_X_by_code(node.right,code);
        }
    }
    return node.element;
```

}