# Linked Binary Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am having problem figuring out how to get my search function to work for my binary tree it returns true for the root but I don't know how to go about traversing the rest of the tree.

```
public boolean contains(Object e)
     {
         return search(root, e);
     }

private boolean search(BinaryNode n, Object e)
    {

        //If the current node is null,
         //then the value clearly isn't found and return false.

         if (n == null) 
         {
             return false;
    } 
        //If the node contains the search value,
        //then the value is found and return true.
         if(n.getValue() == e)
        {
            return true;
        }


         //If the node isn't null but also doesn't contain the search value,
         //then search both the left and right subtrees

         return false;

     }
```

Comment: This is a well documented process, use google.

Comment: yes just google. suppose this is a duplicate [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938486/how-to-search-for-a-node-in-a-tree-and-return-it).

Comment: I've been googling this for hours. The function has to be like this so it will run with the test program my professor gave me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of `Contains()` from some golang code I had lying around on my desktop. You could port it to Java.

```
// Contains indicated whether or not a value is in the tree.
func (tree *Tree) Contains(value int) bool {
    return (tree.find(tree.Root, value) != nil)
}

// find will search for a node containing a given value, in a tree whose
// root node is root.
func (tree *Tree) find(root *Node, value int) *Node {
    if nil == root {
        return nil
    }

    if value > root.Data {
        return tree.find(root.Right, value)
    } else if value < root.Data {
        return tree.find(root.Left, value)
    } // else, root.Data == node.Data

    return root
}
```